# Properly working with vector files

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, davinci-resolve

I have a project that I've edited in Davinci Resolve 12 where I want to add a logo in the beginning. However, Resolve won't import either PDF, SVG or EPS format, so I created a high resolution PNG of the logo instead. Even though the PNG file looks fine on its own when looking at it, when bringing it into Resolve, it gets very pixely.

As a backup solution, I tried importing the original PDF into Final Cut Pro X instead and exporting a MOV file that I could bring into Resolve. However, the logo got pixely when exporting it from FCPX as well.

So, I'm at a bit of a loss here. How could I properly work with vector files so that the result looks smooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I solved it myself, and it wasn't pretty.

To be able to work with my vector file in Davinci Resolve 12 (and in Final Cut Pro X without loosing any detail), I first had to convert it into a font. Yes, you read that correctly. I had to create a font where I assigned my logo to a specific character and then use the font in my editing program.

More specifically, to achieve this, I used the excellent [Icomoon web app](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) where I could import my vector image, assign it to a character code (in my case, I used "30", which stands for numeric zero in standard [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding).

[image]

Then I simply downloaded my font, installed it on the system as any other custom font, and accessed it as a text object in Davinci Resolve 12.

[image]

What a time to be alive!